# How I catch froala editor on focus event?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, addeventlistener, onfocus, froala

I must wirte a eventListener function for froala editor on focus event. But I couldn't found any event callback on [documentation](http://editor.froala.com/callbacks) and couldn't found any input element this editor's structure.

This is focused [froalaeditor](http://editor.froala.com/) structure snapshot.

[image: Focused Frolaeditor structure]

What is the way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Official documentation](https://editor.froala.com/events#focus), you write this:

```
$(".selector").on('editable.focus', function (e, editor) {
  // editor focused
});
```

And blur:

```
$(".selector").on('editable.blur', function (e, editor) {
  // editor blurred
});
```

And to detach the focus event:

```
$(".selector").off('editable.focus');

$(".selector").off('editable.blur');
```

Comment: '.selector' should be selector of the Froala editor element or the destination element?

Comment: Just FYI for others, for react variant you pass it in the editor config object under 'events' key

Comment: With this callback, how do you get the the new/changed HTML from the editor object? Update: figured it out, the new HTML is at editor.el.innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after the post my question via try and error method.
the focusin function of jQuery catching any element's focus event.

this is the test code:

```
      $("#editor").focusin(function(){ 
                                         console.log("editor is focused");                       
                }).focusout(function(){
                                         console.log("editor is blured"); 
                 });
```